# Connecting 8 x 500GB SATA drives to HP Smart Array P800 controller on 2 external mini ports

Tags: hp, hardware-raid, sata, hp-smart-array, external-connection

I have already 8 drives hooked up the the P800 RAID controller internally. I would like to attach 8 more SATA drives externally. I looked in the documentation but the only thing mentioned for the external ports is `HP SAS to Mini Cables` with different length options.

The question is:

#### Do I have to get the HP 50 or 60 Modular Smart Array in order to hook up the hard drives to the external ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly you need it to be one of the HP disk enclosures yes but the P800 supports the MSA 50, 60 & 70.